# Using `Maybe` with Data Constructor

Tags: haskell

I'm working on implementing a `todo` command-line app in Haskell. Thanks for [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#command-line-arguments) for the challenge.

In particular, I'm curious about my `Action` data constructor (supposed to be an enumeration basically) for my `Action` data type.

```
data Action = Add | View | Delete      -- 3 options for the tood list

...

execute :: (Maybe Action) -> IO a
execute Just Add    = print "Add not supported"
execute Just View   = view
execute Just Delete = print "Delete not supported"
execute None        = print "invalid user input"
```

When compiling via `ghc --make ...`, I get an error:

`Not in scope: data constructor`None'`

How can I properly use `Maybe Action`? Am I incorrectly assuming that `Maybe` can be attached to any data type instance, i.e. constructor?

Please correct me if I'm using the wrong terminology (data type, constructor, etc).

Comment: 1. Parentheses required: `execute (Just Add) = ...` 2. The constructor you are looking for is `Nothing`, not `None`. 3. Parentheses around `Maybe Action` not required. 4. `Maybe` can indeed be used with any data type (I've never hear anyone say 'data type instance')

Comment: The definition of `Maybe` is `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`. From where are you getting `None`? It should be `Nothing`.

Answer (score 6):

The specific error you're getting is because the empty constructor for `Maybe` is `Nothing`, not `None`.  However, once you fix that you'll get some other baffling error message because you need to parenthesize.

```
execute :: (Maybe Action) -> IO a
execute (Just Add)    = print "Add not supported"
execute (Just View)   = view
execute (Just Delete) = print "Delete not supported"
execute Nothing       = print "invalid user input"
```

Otherwise, it would assume that you meant for `execute` to have *two* arguments - one for each pattern in its equations.